# strange rectangle obscuring the view when chrome or safari are maximized

Tags: google-chrome, multiple-monitors, safari-5, webkit

I have a strange issue that happens with both the Chrome and Safari browsers. It only happens when the browser is maximized on my 2nd monitor.

A rather large (toolbar sized) rectangle obscures the top-left of my window. It occupies about half the screens width and is a few textlines high. It is filled with junk or old screen contents. It does not scroll.

Hard to describe but here is a screenshot (I've added the red box).

[image]

So, is this a known problem? Anything I can do about it?

Comment: Well, at least I guess it's safe to say that it's Webkit related.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg - yes, that kind of reassured me. Makes malware less likely.

Comment: Operating system?

Comment: It's running on Win7 HP, SP1. Second monitor on HDMI, both are 1920x1080

Comment: Do you have DWM disabled?

Answer (score 0):

You have to update video drivers since modern drivers do not allow to reduce hardware acceleration level on Win7 to eliminatie "artifacts"

Comment: But what makes you think that this is an acceleration artifact?

Comment: Because millions of others do not have it?